# NodeJS script will not start when executed in seperate application

Tags: bash, node.js

I have a separate application that runs a shell script called test.sh:

```
node server.js;   //listen on port 5555
```

the script works fine if I run it as root: `./test.sh`?

**Maybe...**

- a permissions error with nodejs?
- nodejs script is crashing because it writes the server status to stdout but stdout doesnt exist?

thank you in advance...

Comment: Which user are you trying to execute with? What are the permissions of the file?

Comment: permissions are 777. Im executing the script with a seperate user

Comment: Check also the permissions of the directories. Does the user launching the script have access to all of them?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply... I used chmod 777 recursively for all files server.js uses. Maybe node itself cannot be used by another user?

Comment: Instead of using ./test.sh, try using <sh path> <test.sh absolute path>, like /bin/sh /var/.../test.sh. And try to execute it with the user launching the application, just to see if it is a permissions problem or other things.

Comment: Ok. i used the absolute path and sudo to execute as other user... it works fine on command line. but still no luck in the seperate application runs it.

Comment: No, no, if you use sudo it will be executed by root. Test it without sudo to see if the user can execute. Then paste here the error you get.

Comment: but what if i used sudo -u theotheruser /var/lib/test.sh ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I misconfused. Did you already put the whole path in the script? Otherwise I am a bit blur about what could go next.

Answer (score 0):

use forever to run your node server
Install forever through npm

npm install forever -g

You can configure logs to write your stdout

You can run your app as forever server.js

the same you can give in your .sh file also